# Configure Solr for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, solr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache solr configuration with tomcat 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026014/apache-solr-configuration-with-tomcat-6-0)

I am using tomcat 6.0 and running Solr in it. Can some one help me how to configure solr to index SQL Server DB?