# Integrate solr with mySql

Tags: mysql, solr

How can I integrate solr with mysql. I have deployed the solr server and all, so what I have to do next for performing search?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559528/configure-solr-for-sql-server Though this question is for SQL Server, I don't think the configuration is database specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the ans

First have to do a full import which will index all the data in the database(indexing will make the search faster)full import can be started by hitting the below mentioned url in the browser.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
```

If the database is so big and if we are performing full import several times it will take lots of time to avoid that we can do partial import by hitting the below url

```
localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import
```

When delta-import command is executed, it reads the start time stored in conf/dataimport.properties. It uses that timestamp to run delta queries and after completion, updates the timestamp in conf/dataimport.properties

After performing imports our solr is ready to perform search
we can simply hit this

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=chair&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

url in the browser to get the result(here I am searching for the chairs, it will return 10 results)

Comment: i am encounter with (HTTP Status 404 - /solr/dataimport) error when i try hit this (http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import)   URL

Comment: Is your Tomcat/jetty server up and running?

Comment: Where do I put dataimport.properties file?